# JSON Encode characters in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to return a value using php and AJAX but I get the following returned when doing so. This part of my code has been functional in previous projects so I am a little stumped as to why it is happening now.

The returned value:

> ‹������«VÊÏV²2ÔQ*.)V²qjÜ¥5¼���

it should return something like this:

```
{"ok":1,"status":"ok"}
```

The PHP I am using:

```
$response = array('ok' => 0);
if($results)
{
    $response['ok'] = 1;
    $response['status'] = ($visible == 'visible') ? 'ok' : 'no';
}

ob_clean();
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($response, true);
exit;
```

Now if I removed the code and put into its own file it works fine. I have all files and database set to UTF-8 also.

Comment: Remove `true` from `json_encode` parameters

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this has no affect.

Comment: try to remove ob_clean(); or you could try to print_r($response); after the ob_clean(); I suspect that it cleared your output of $response thus it return nothing when you echo json_encode($response);

Comment: this code is almost correct, show us how you use it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I removed the ob_clean() it adds the html back into the response and the array is returned correctly. But I only want to return the array, if that makes sense?

Comment: remove the header related and use return instead of echo if you are using ajax otherwise if you just want to print it out then use echo.

Comment: so just use:  ob_clean(); return json_encode($response);

Comment: this returns the following: ‹íS1n„0ìïé,º4nˆÒ¥Ê»KGf‰t¿¿_¤À‰ô±dKöŒgÇ;2À2òÝ·9ímŸ´†÷€ÖCúÆÅ²¶‘AëKî€ÃBuS×‰© övn§Ð:$h,’23 ê–ˆ‚T#sè/_T¨´¹ëÔ>¤-[nèÜý¾ÕR©/ÇQª<³ëh8çY’1yûbòl^¦7þ6Q¼¨]´ ×o`Å=ÈÔH=oÛ3åd}q²-ñ‰ä0ôåO·µº¨%Ã»Á½’'¦¹áLüí±EBÖ=-…p8³·pè§5áá7[ä¥°tÉœ¤‘ÜysâÌA"

Comment: I think you don't need the ob_clean but since I can't really see the output, so you should try both with and without the ob_clean. Then see which is the preferred output or expected output you want. Are you using ajax or something to get the json?

Comment: I have added in the JS to the ajax call above. I technically only need to return {"ok":1,"status":"ok"} but if I run the file in the browser (no ajax) I get the same response invalid characters.

Comment: I'm confused about the relevance of all that JavaScript you've shared.  Being a simple GET request, do you mean that it only breaks when you process it with JavaScript? It looks fine otherwise?

Comment: No apologies but previous replies requested it? The code is fully functional in previous projects. even if I just add a simple a normal arrays and output it with json_encode I still get the same response (invalid characters). I will removed the above JS as irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself. I know the code works fine in *another* project but what happens if you type the JSON URL in the browser location bar in *current* project? Is that output you've posted?

Comment: I tried to create a simple test with ajax and direct access to the php, both work fine return {'ok':0}. If you want I can put it up as an answer.

Comment: Do you use some kind of output compression?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yes this is the output if I go directly to the url.

Comment: @Gumbo the only compression is: Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch. The  dev server is the latest MAMP Pro php v5.5.1

Comment: @iCezz if I add the code to a file on its own it outputs correctly this is what is making me think it's a) an encoding issue. b) previous code is corrupting the output?

Comment: @neoszion No, that just says what your client accepts. Have a look at the [zlib runtime configuration](http://php.net/zlib.configuration) and also check how you call [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) because you mayhave registered [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler) as output buffer handler.

Comment: @Gumbo your comments helped me figure it out see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate closing parentheses on line 2.

It should be:

```
$response = array('ok' => 0);
if($results)
{
```

Fixing that, your code works for me:

```
{"ok":0}
```

And if I force `$results = true;` :

```
{"ok":1,"status":"no"}
```

Comment: Apologies but this was a typo when adding in the question. If I just run a simple array with values I still get the invalid characters as a response. Hence the reason the code is valid from previous projects. I have a feeling its file type encoding?

Comment: The second parameter of json_encode is an optional integer and you are using a boolen. New flags have been added on PHP 5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Where you running PHP < 5.4 on those previous projects you mentioned?

Comment: I upgraded to the newer version of MAMP Pro for mac, it runs PHP 5.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid now, I was running ob_gzhandler within my ob_start();

Apologies to all.